# A proof about strong continuity

Tags: general-topology

I have the following statement: Given a function $f:(X,\tau_X)\rightarrow (Y, \tau_Y)$, where $(X,\tau_X)$, $(Y,\tau_Y)$ are topological spaces, prove that: $f(\bar{A})\subset f(A)$ for all $A \subset X$ if and only if $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed for all $B\subset Y$.

I only want to show that given that $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed, for all $B\subset Y$, then $f(\bar{A})\subset f(A)$, for all $A \subset X$. That will imply strong continuity. I tried proving it by the method of inclusions, that is, given $y \in f(\bar{A})$, then $y\in f(A)$, but I couldn't figure out how to prove it. I would appreciate a lot if you can give me a hint about how to proceed or if there is an alternate route for me to take in order to reach the desire conclusion. Thank you a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\subseteq X$. Then $f^{-1}[f[A]]$ is closed, and clearly $A\subseteq f^{-1}[f[A]]$, so $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq f^{-1}[f[A]]$. But then

$$f[\operatorname{cl}A]\subseteq f\left[f^{-1}[f[A]]\right]=f[A]\,,$$

as desired.

**Added:** This is a very strong condition. Let $A\subseteq Y$ be arbitrary. Then $f^{-1}[A]=X\setminus f^{-1}[Y\setminus A]$, so $f^{-1}[A]$ is clopen in $X$. It follows that if $\mathscr{F}=\left\{f^{-1}[\{y\}]:y\in Y\right\}$, the set of fibres of $f$, then $\mathscr{F}$ is a base for a [partition topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_topology) $\tau_f\subseteq\tau_X$.

Comment: Doesn't this also mean that $f(A)=f(\overline{A})$, since we already have $A\subseteq \overline{A}$ implying $f(A)\subseteq f(\overline{A})$?

Comment: @CSquared: It does indeed. I’ve not seen this condition before, but it looks rather strong.